# Converting dllimport from vb6 to c# 3.5

Tags: c#, vb6, interop, dllimport, vb6-migration

I have some code in VB6 which imports a function from a dll, it uses the byVal and byRef keywords, I want to convert that code into C# 3.5.

1. Is there going to be a problem with unicode encoding of the strings?
2. Do I declare the varibles that are "byRef" in vb6 into "ref" varibles in the C# code?
3. It seams that return value is entered into a string send by the VB6 code as  a "byVal" parameter, how does that work, aren't you supposed to send stuff "byRef", if you want to allow the function to edit the string? Is this concept still going to work with my C# code?

I tryed coping the function declaration from VB6, the parameter types are just int's, long's and string. Where there was a "byVal" keyword I just left it empty and replaced "byRef" keywords with the "ref" keyword in C# and the code dosn't work.

The VB6 Code:

```
Private Declare Function Foo Lib "Foo_Functions.dll" (ByVal a as String, ByVal b
 as Long, ByVal c as String, ByVal d as String, ByVal e as String, ByVal f
 as String, ByVal g as Long, ByVal h as String, ByVal i as String, ByRef j
 as Long, ByRef k as Long) As 
Integer
```

My C# 3.5 Translation:

```
[Dllimkport("foo_functions.dll")] public static extern int foo(String a, long b,
 string c, string d, string e, string f, long g, string h, stringbuilder i,
 ref long j, ref long k);
```

Please help, I'v already spent a whole day on this :p....

In the end I converted the function call to a VB.NET lib, using the automatic project converter (from VB6 to VB.NET 2008), and called it using C# reference.

Thanks.

Comment: I might help if you were to include the VB6 declare for the imported function in your question.  Without any code to work from its difficult to properly understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to call the function in a win32 dll from c#?

Comment: Note also, that Long variables in VB6 are the same as Int32 (int) in C#.

Comment: I would suggest pasting into your question the very original DLL function declaration in its original language (most likely C). I suggest that simply because often times imports in VB6 were made to things like Integer when it really ought to be Int32 in C# b/c the original C returned a HANDLE. It's hard to tell unless we get the very original.

Answer (score 3):

Modifiable byVal strings should work if you replace them with `StringBuilder` in C#.
Another possible solution is to use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string i`.

I used the "Upgrade Visual Basic 6 code..." tool in Visual Studio and this resulted in the following VB.NET code:

```
Private Declare Function Foo Lib "Foo_Functions.dll" (ByVal a As String, _
  ByVal b As Integer, ByVal c As String, ByVal d As String, ByVal e As _
  String, ByVal f As String, ByVal g As Integer, ByVal h As String, ByVal i _
  As String, ByRef j As Integer, ByRef k As Integer) As Short
```

Note that VB6 `Long` was converted to `Integer` and VB6 `Integer` was converted to `Short`.
I then used reflector to see how it should look like in C#:

```
[DllImport("Foo_Functions.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true)]
private static extern short Foo([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref
  string a, int b, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string c,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string d,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string e,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string f, int g,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string h,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string i, ref int j, ref int k);
```

This is the exact translation of the VB6 declaration and should have the same behaviour. If this still doesn't work then perhaps you could describe how exactly it doesn't work (does the unmanaged function ever get called, are the arguments garbage, are the returned values garbage, something else?).

Comment: Try the VBByRefStr variant and also add CharSet=CharSet.Unicode to the DllImport attribute if needed.

Comment: I converted the original code VB6 -> VB.NET -> C# and got this declaration, maybe this works?

Answer (score 2):

have a look at [www.pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net) It shows C# and VB.net examples.

Comment: As I understand, this tool is only for calling dll's connected to the windows operating systems, and not custom ones.

Comment: Yes you are correct. It has various examples of dllImport calls for windows API's etc. The examples may help you convert VB to C#.

Comment: the examples would help you convert **VB.Net** to C# but not **VB6**. The OP needs to convert **VB6** to C#.

Comment: @MarkJ: Sure, my answer is more about the examples of dll imports, which may help as one may be just looking for a solution or example in either of these languages, rather than a direct/specific conversion.

Answer (score 1):

If a VB6 Declare statement which includes `ByVal s As String`, that parameter will be marshalled as a pointer to an ANSI string. I would try changing the DLLImport to `[DllImport("Foo_Functions.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]`

For output parameters, you will need to use `StringBuilder s` and also preinitialise the StringBuilder large enough to hold the output. For input parameters, you can use `String s`

Do you have a C declaration for the DLL? Mabe in the original vendor's documentation, or the DLL source code? If so, there is a free tool [CLRInsideOut](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/CLRInsideOut2008_01.exe) that will convert that C declaration to C# or VB.Net PInvoke code. Read more [on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx).

Disclaimer: [JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar) should really get any rep points for this answer since he [wrote some of the tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2008/03/14/making-pinvoke-easy.aspx).